# Is it possible to play recording on twilio autopilot and get NLU?

Tags: twilio, text-to-speech

I'm wanting to use twilio autopilot for a outbound calling project, but I am not a huge fan of AWS Polly text-to-speech (at least over the phone). I thought an easy way around this would be to get text-to-speech audio from Google Cloud (or somewhere else) and instead of using something like this:

```
{
"actions": [
    {
        "say": "Hello World!"
    },
    {
        "listen": true
    }
  ]
}
```

It would be something more like this:

```
    {
"actions": [
    {
        "say": <recording link or file>         
    },
    {
        "listen": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to play audio recordings instead of the text-to-speech twilio has AND have the NLU aspect of autopilot?

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's no way to use a file to play a response within Autopilot. Since the `say` response could be sent to an SMS message or chat message as well as a voice call, including a URL would not make sense.

You can update or change the voice you use using the Autopilot's stylesheet. This allows you to choose which voice you use, [including all the Polly voices as well as the basic man, woman and alice](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/twiml/text-to-speech) that Twilio supports.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. I know you can play audio recordings with twilio voice, but you give up the NLU. There isn't a way to use NLU in Twilio voice is there?

Comment: One option you have could be to use Gather with speech input and use the Autopilot API query API with the `SpeechResult` to return the action and then use `<Play>` to play audio. I’ve not tried this before, but it might work.

Comment: Let me know how you get on!